# Get-ChildItem Fails When Using a Variable With the Include Switch

Tags: windows, variables, powershell

Powershell v4.0
Windows 7

This code works and retrieves the 2 files I'm trying to find:

```
$dir = Get-Item -Path "C:\TestSource"
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($dir.FullName)\*" -File -Include *.txt,*.inf
```

This code works too, but it only finds the txt file:

```
$Dir = Get-Item -Path "C:\TestSource"
$Filter = "*.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($dir.FullName)\*" -File -Include $Filter
```

However, this does not return any objects:

```
$Dir = Get-Item -Path "C:\TestSource"
$Filter = "*.txt,*.inf"
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($dir.FullName)\*" -File -Include $Filter
```

It's necessary to build the $Filter variable into an array like so:

```
$Dir = Get-Item -Path "C:\TestSource"
$Filter = @("*.txt","*.inf")
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($dir.FullName)\*" -File -Include $Filter
```

The Microsoft page on [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx) leads me to believe it's possible to use variables with the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.  However, why is the cmdlet not returning objects unless the variable is an array?  Since the explicit string works in the first example, shouldn't the 3rd example work as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `Include` is always an array - in your first example `-Include *.txt,*.inf` passes a two-element array as the filter.

In your third example it is a comma-separated string. If you pass an array it should work:

```
$Dir = Get-Item -Path "C:\TestSource"
$Filter = "*.txt", "*.inf"
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($dir.FullName)\*" -File -Include $Filter
```

Comment: Yea, that I figured out.....  But I reworked my question (3 minutes before you posted) to find ask why.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and that makes complete sense.

Comment: Additionally, Get-ChildItem passes the -Include arguments on to the File System Provider, it doesn't actually process those arguments itself. When it passes `-Include *.txt,*.ini` powershell sees an array of two strings. When it is told ".txt,.ini" it sees a 9 character long string, so it passes that string to the provider, which then looks for files containing the string `"*.txt,*.ini"` which it will never find.

Answer (score 0):

Lee gave the answer; in your third example you are trying to pass multiple values for the -Include parameter to evaluate but you didn't format it appropriately as an array so the script is looking for a file with this entire string pattern in its name: `*.txt,*.inf`

Comment: You might have lost track of the edit times.  At the time I wrote my first comment, he hadn't edited his answer yet.